# Time efficient functionality to add border in excel data using python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Is there a time efficient way to add border to data in excel , currently I am using the following snippet which uses **xlwings** range function but it takes a lot of time to add borders.

```
from xlwings import Range
    for cell in Range('C22').current_region:
        for border_id in range(7,12):
            cell.api.Borders(border_id).LineStyle = 1
            cell.api.Borders(border_id).Weight = 2
```

I am generating a comprehensive report in excel using python & If I use the above code for adding border it would take hours.

I know that xlsxwriter is way faster than **xlwings** and have functionality to add border but it is just a writer it can't update already existing spreadsheet.

Comment: Set the border on whole range, not cells

Comment: how can we achieve that I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on looping on all cells of a range and applying the same operations many times, you can directly apply your two operations on the whole range. For example, if your sheet is called Test, you can do:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(EXCEL_FILENAME)
sht = wb.sheets[EXCEL_SHEETNAME]

sht.range('A1:C7').api.Borders.LineStyle = 1
sht.range('A1:C7').api.Borders.Weight = 2
```